# Copy range from workbook to another without open

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I'm trying to copy a range of values from a workbook to another by using a dialog box to select the file I'd like to copy the data from.

I'd like also not to open the "copyFrom" workbook in the process. The problem lies in passing the file path in the string "filename" to the workbook variable "copyFrom".

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub butt_copy_Click()

    Call copy1

End Sub

Private Sub copy1()

    Dim fileName As String, copyFrom As Workbook

    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    copyFrom = filename  

    Sheet1.Range("A1:A20") = copyFrom.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1:A20")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below. But i have some Clarification like where will you run the code from

```
Application.Visible=False
Set copyFrom = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
```

Then Try below. Worked Perfectly for me

```
Private Sub copy1()
 Dim app As New Excel.Application
 Dim fileName As String, copyFrom As Workbook
 app.Visible = False
 fileName = app.GetOpenFilename()

 Set copyFrom = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
  MsgBox copyFrom.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
 'Sheet1.Range("A1:A20") = copyFrom.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1:A20")


End Sub
```

Comment: The logic works. The problem is that I would like to run the macro from the copyTo workbook without the copyFrom workbook opening. (it really slipped from the questions, really sorry)

Comment: Check my Updated Code

Comment: Yay, it works! Thank you. What happens is that the file is opened, but not shown, right?

Comment: Correct. Can you please Mark it as answered. So that it will be ready to use for other who tries the same

Comment: Yes, definitely. That was my next step

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment to add to the algorithm;
It opens the file and reads from it, but does not close. This makes it "READ_ONLY" for all other users!

I suggest that at the end of the code: add this for saving original file unchanged.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
app.Workbooks.Close savechanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```